# Bokeh charts unresponsive on rangeslider on_change

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh

I am working on bokeh charts for the first time. I have followed a few tutorials but due to some reason, update function is not working on rangeslider on_change()

```
def make_data(df, start, end):
#df['ID'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
s = df['ID'] >= start
e = df['ID'] <= end
df1 = df[e & s]
date = df1['date'].tolist()
capi = df1['capi'].tolist()
data = {'x': dateTime(date), 'y': capi}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
return source

def update(attr, old, new):
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("main_data.csv", index_col = None)
df['ID'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
new_src = make_dataset(df, range_start = range_select.value[0], range_end = range_select.value[1])
source.data.update(new_src.data)

def make_plot(source):
p1 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Stock Closing Prices")
p1.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
p1.line('x', 'y', source = source, color='#A6CEE3', legend='capi')
return p1

range_select = RangeSlider(title="Date range", value=(ids[0], ids[100]), start=ids[0], end=ids[-1], step=1)
range_select.on_change('value', update)
source = make_data(df, 1, 1000)
p = make_plot(source)
controls = WidgetBox(range_select)
layout = column(controls, p)
tab = Panel(child=layout, title = 'Histogram')
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab])
show(tabs)
```

can someone please point me in the right direction here

Comment: Real python callbacks, i.e. with `on_change`, only work when run on the Bokeh server. The presence of `show` in your code suggests that you are not running this as a Bokeh server application. Please refer to [Running a Bokeh Server](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) in the documentation.

Comment: thank you for your response @bigreddot. However when i replace show(tabs) with curdoc().add_root(tabs) and run via bokeh server, the behaviour stays the same

Comment: If you fix the code formatting in your post, and add to it to make it a *complete* script, I'd be happy to run it for a closer look.